# Outside Database

Tags: views, database

I have an outside database called "panels" that stores our company articles/blog posts/products etc... in it.
Is there a good module to use, or I could write a custom module to hook into the outside database to display these content types?
All changes would be done through our in house system, I am only looking to display them onto the drupal site we made for our store front.

Comment: Just for clarification, so you have two databases? One which contains Drupal for your store front and the other outside one?

Comment: Or do you have 1 database that you want to be in a different location from your files folder, php, mysql etc..

Comment: I have 2 databases.  One which is the drupal site/store front as we refer to it and the other that is separate and holds our company content that feeds 4 sites.  We have the non drupal sites displaying our content, just trying to find out the best way for my drupal stores to display them.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is one database is for products, and is the drupal store database, the other database never saves into a node but only displays, like a feed.

Comment: For anyone else interested in using an outside source to display info but not have it save in the Drupal database the best solution I found was to write your own hooks and use Views/Page Manager to display the info.

Comment: http://barcelona2012.drupaldays.org/sessions/displaying-external-data-fly-views-and-ctools

Comment: That was the base I used to write my own code to accomplish my needs.  Great presentation I hope someone else looking into this can find his presentation and make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

You may have some success with [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) which will enable you to import data from an external source into a Drupal content type. You could set up a cron task to run the migration on a regular basis.

Comment: This seems promising, as all I really need it to do is take the data I pull into a block and then display control where it outputs through page manager or contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363) module? It is built of the idea of using SQL to get data out of a database and use XHTML and CSS to format it into web reports. Visit the [Forena HowTos](https://www.drupal.org/node/2443761) page for some links (near the bottom) to some live demo / showcase links.

DBMSs that are supported are the Drupal DB itself (of course), but also MySQL, Oracle, MS SQL, Postgress, Sqite, anything PDO compliant.

Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena),
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: Forena is something I am looking into and it may serve my needs.  I will research more into this module and Migrate and see what fits our needs.